# How to correctly compare output of typeid(...).name() to character type in C++?

Tags: c++, input

Trying to test if a particular input matches the ideal data type, i.e. if I get an input check if it an int.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
   
   string integer;
   cin >> integer;
   if (typeid(stoi(integer)).name() != "i") {
      cout << "Bad input";
   }
   
   return 0;
}
```

But it always says that it is not equal to "i".

Tried changing to 'i', haven't found any other functions that might work, open to suggestions.

Comment: The behavior depends on the implementation. You can't portably rely on the result.

Comment: You understand that the type name is fixed at compile-time? (At least when classes with virtual functions are not involved.) Whatever you're trying to do, you're not doing it correctly. Are you trying to check if the number is within range?

Comment: Just call std::stoi, if it fails your input wasn't an integer. After that you can try another conversion etc... I would not write code that makes decissions on type id. In any case all your inputs will be std::string now.

Comment: just use boost demangle.

Comment: What actually you are trying to achieve? This `cout << "Bad input";` suggest that you try accomplish something else then you have described.

Comment: Note that the condition is always false since you are comparing a `const char*` with a string literal. If you want to compare them as strings, you need to use some suitable function, such as `strcmp`. Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/77M1x4YKK.

Comment: `std::stoi` returns `int`. Full stop. Checking its type won't give you any useful information. If the string could not be converted to an integer value, [`std::stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) throws an exception. To check whether the conversion failed, catch the exception.